# Leaflet Routing not showing path

Tags: javascript, routes, leaflet

My leaflet routing suddenly not showing the shortest path, instead of having red line between two points it will just show the two points.

Here is my code

```
function resetRouting(){
   if(map.hasLayer(routelayer)){
        map.removeLayer(routelayer);
   }
}
function doRouting(){
    resetRouting();
    routelayer = new L.layerGroup();
    map.addLayer(routelayer);

    route = L.Routing.control({
        waypoints: [
            L.latLng(latA, lonA),
            L.latLng(latB, lonB)
        ],
        routeWhileDragging: true,
        reverseWaypoints: true,
        showAlternatives: false,
        altLineOptions: {
            styles: [
                {color: 'black', opacity: 0.15, weight: 9},
                {color: 'white', opacity: 0.8, weight: 6},
                {color: 'blue', opacity: 0.5, weight: 2}
            ]
        }
    });

    routelayer.addLayer(route);
}
```

Comment: What Leaflet/plugins/services are you using and what versions? When/how did it stop working?

Comment: I used this leaflet [Here](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine) It stopped working maybe almost 2 months after I used it on my website.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I would comment instead of answer, but I have no enough points reputation.
Could you post the whole code? Where did you add the control to the map?
I don't get why you use a LayerGroup, routelayer, I guess you did it to add the control to the map, but you can do it in a very straightforward manner instead:
The basic plugin use:
http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/tutorials/basic-usage/

Comment: @localdisknoob Here is a JsFiddle of the example I mentioned above, span the map if is necessary to see the path red line: http://jsfiddle.net/rossig7/rtq941za/